# Simplifying Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean, signal-processing, boolean-logic, digital-logic

I am trying to prove that `BC + !A!B + !A!C = ABC +!A`

I have attempted using De Morgan laws, and substituting `X for !A!B` and `Y for !A!C`, however I made no headway in this.

I"ve alos tried gruopoing the A's like so, `!A(!B+!C)`, however again I couldn't get anywhere. If anyone could point me in the right direction, help me solve, show me a tool that can do it, etc. I'd be grateful.

Comment: Belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  BC + !A!B + !A!C
= BC + !A(!B + !C)          distributive law
= BC + !A!(BC)              De Morgan's law
= (A + !A)BC + !A!(BC)      identity and x OR !x = true
= A(BC) + !A(BC) + !A!(BC)  distributive law
= ABC + !A((BC) + !(BC))    distributive law
= ABC + !A                  x OR !x = true and identity
```